# Saving Large Data To database

Tags: android, sqlite

in My game, I have A Set Of Points For Each Level, called "Points", "Points1" And "Points2"

for example in level 1 i have these Points:

Level 1:

Poitns: (0.3,0.04),(0.2,0.25),(1.5,0.5),(0.2,0.5),(0.3,0.04)

Poitns1: (0.5,0.04),(0.6,0.35),(0.5,0.5),(0.2,0.5),(0.3,0.04),(0.2,0.04)

Poitns2: (0.3,0.04),(0.6,0.34),(0.5,0.5),(0.2,0.5),(0.3,0.04),(0.3,0.04)

Level 2:...

Level 3: ...

i have about 90 levels in my game and each have its Data,

the question is, How Can i Save thees data to DataBase?

One Option is To Create a table for Each, Point1.x , Point1.y, Point2.x and...

this will be a big database, with 6 tables.

another Option is to save Data for All Point1 data in a table as String, and pull out float numbers by parsing ( for example save 0.3,0.2,1.5,0.2,0.3,0.04 for points.x and then parse the data for each row and check when it reaches to ","...) 
but this is a so Heavy operation for Android.

What will be the best Choice? is there an alternative way except database?

and if Not, How should i save these data to use less memory for calculation and reaching the data?

Comment: Are the number of Points in each level equal? I mean "Points" "Point1" "Point2" and no more or less? Also "Points" always has 5 parentheses elements and "Points1" with "Points2" always have 6 parentheses elements?

Comment: @Marat no there is no Role for that, All may be diffrent, for each Level, And the number of points is diffrent for each level too

Comment: Create two kinds of Table: Level & Points. Then in each Level set proper Points.

Comment: I assume your 90 level each have 1000 points which equals to 90000 double and it's not much memory don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using SQLite db. It is a great tool to save and work with texts. I'm not familiar with other databases, but I can tell you my view on how to solve this if you would use SQLite db. Hope that other people would answer and tell about alternative databases, so that you would compare them all.

As you have said, you could store all floating point numbers for one Point in single string. Then create only one table to store all of the data. It would look something like this.

```
 _id  | Points  |  Level 1  |  Level 2  |  Level 3  | ... | Level 90
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   | Point1  | "0.3,..." | "0.4,..." | "0.3,..." | ... | "0,6,..."
  2   | Point2  | "0.2,..." |    null   | "0.1,..." | ... |   null
  3   | Point3  | "0.3,..." | "0.5,..." | "0.4,..." | ... | "0.2,..."
...
...
```

By `null` I mean the levels where particular Point is not applicable. Or you may write instead  just empty string `""`. And `_id` is the PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT column just to manage auto insert of new Point rows (will not affect on your data).

The idea is that in this manner you could have any number of rows and fixed number of columns (in this case 90). However, there could be other better or similar solutions for table.

Considering the speed of modern processors (1-2GHz/core) you can have up to billion operation done in one second. Compare this number to the size of your string elements. I'm sure that your Points string will not be too long to obtain significant time to process it when extracting from db. Therefore, you don't need to worry about speed. You can even launch this processes in background so that it will not affect on your UI.

**Disadvantages:**

It is not easy to create 90 columns by hardcoding all of them inside of `onCreate` inside of SQLiteOpenHelper. But it is only one time job to do.

So that was my solution. Hope it helps you somehow. I'm also curious to know about other Databases that could help solve this problem easier if it is possible.

Comment: @Alireza.pir was my answer helpful for you? If yes consider accepting and upvoting my answer. I will appreciate it.